# Форматирование текстового файла

Tags: c, строки, файлы

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть задача:

```
   Форматирование по трапеции. Читая исходный файл, формировать отцентрированные строки переменной ширины без переноса слов и сохранить в другом файле. 
Первая строка шириной 60 позиций, каждая следующая на 2 позиции короче, до 40 поз. 
Потом ширина увеличивается до 60 позиций и т.д. 
Центрирование осуществляется равномерной вставкой дополнительных пробелов.
```

Набросок кода который работает не полностью выполняя условия задания, т.е. если нет конца строки в тексте и переносит слова.

Как сделать, чтобы при считывании строки из файла символ конца строки убирался и добавить к строке дополнительные символы пробелов (или слов из следующей строки)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

FILE *fp=fopen("first.txt","rt");
FILE *sp=fopen("second.txt","wt");
char Str[61], str1[61], str2[61];
int n=60,i=0;
//*char prob = "  ";

if((fp)==NULL)
    {
    printf("error file first.txt not open. \n\r");
    getchar();
    exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("file first.txt open.\n\r");
        if((sp)==NULL)
            {
            printf("error file  second.txt not open. \n\r");
        }else{
            while(n>=40)
            {
                n=n-i;
                strcpy(str1,fgets(Str,n,fp));
                for(int j=1;j<i/2;j++){fputs(" ",sp);}
                fputs(str1,sp);
                for(int j=1;j<i/2;j++){fputs(" ",sp);}
                fputs("\n",sp);
                i=i+2;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(sp);
    }
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну что нибудь типа

     l = strlen(Str);
     if(Str(l) == '\n') Str[l] = '\0';

И цикл у Вас должен быть не `while(n >= 40)`, а до прочтения EOF.

Comment: но файл то может быть длинным! а нам только несколько дюжин строк надо.

Comment: @AQZ в условии про это не написано. Тогда проверяйте на количество строк. Или на количество строк и EOF, если "файл может быть очень коротким".